# Get the row of latest date

Tags: mysql

Doctrine2 and mysql...

I want to get the row of latest data.

InfoAccount table

```
recordDate score   id
2018-10-10 99      A   // I need this row.
2018-10-9  88      B
2018-10-8  77      C
```

So I use this code.

```
 $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            'SELECT MAX(t.recordDate) 
            FROM App\Entity\InfoAccount t')
```

It just returns the MAX value of t.date.
I would like to get the whole row.

It must be quite simple though,,,,,

Thanks to @scaisEdge

---- i updated like this.

```
'SELECT t 
FROM App\Entity\InfoAccount t
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(recordDate) 
as max_date FROM App\Entity\InfoAccount) k
ON t.max_date = k.recordDate '
```

However it shows the error

`Error: Subquery is not supported here`

Comment: See ORDER BY and LIMIT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select the most recent entry in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659720/how-do-i-select-the-most-recent-entry-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a where date in the subquery

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        ' select * from  App\Entity\Table m 
        where date in (
        SELECT MAX(t.date)  
        FROM App\Entity\Table )' 
        );
```